# How to set up two-way binding between an ItemsSource and a source collection from ReactiveUI in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I've studied [RxUI/collections](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/collections/), [Dynamic Trader](https://github.com/RolandPheasant/Dynamic.Trader) and others, but so far I haven't been able to find an example of how such thing could be wired up.

In my use case, I have a DataGrid which is bound to a collection that comes from a `SourceCache`. When the binding is one-way, this can be achieved as per the docs, i.e. with `Bind()`. Simple.

However, if the DataGrid collection can be modified from the view, e.g. by adding a row, we need a two-way binding. How could we do this with ReactiveUI?

Let me add that I was able to find a solution, but it is a bit ugly and verbose. Basically, the DataGrid collection has to be listened to, but then some mechanism added on both ends, collection and `SourceCache`, to break the loop.

I was wondering if there was a nicer solution?

Comment: "if the DataGrid collection can be modified from the view, e.g. by adding a row, we need a two-way binding" - no, you don't. The reference to collection remains the same, only items inside change

Comment: Yes, why would you need a two-way binding to a source collection?

Comment: Because when `CanUserAddRows` is enabled, the user can click on the last row (which is like a placeholder), and the DataGrid will create a new item and add it to its collection. But now we need to keep it in sync with the source, hence the two-way binding.

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with the same problem and don't know what to do.
There's a out-of-date example which uses ReactiveList which can be found here.
https://github.com/kentcb/YouIandReactiveUI/blob/master/ViewModels/Samples/Chapter%2008/Sample%2001/MainViewModel.cs

However, for dynamic data, I'm confused why the change to ObservableCollection from view like user edit that not fire the IChangeSet that coverted from this ObservableCollection.